# Formula to return percentage of a number up to a maximum value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can someone help me construct a formula in Excel?  I have it close but can't figure out how to incorporate the "Maximum of 5" and "Maximum of 25" for ranges >10-50 and 51+.  See my chart below to calculate sample size given a population.

If Population is:

```
1
>1 - 10
>10 -50
51+
```

Sample Size is:

```
1
2
25% of Population up to a Maximum of 5
10% of Population up to a Maximum of 25
```

My formula now, which does not return what I want:

```
=IF(G4=1,1,IF(AND(G4>1,G4<=10),2,IF(AND(OR(G4>10,G4<=50),(0.25*G4),AND(G4>50,(0.1*G4),G4>25,25)),IF(G4>5,5))))
```

Comment: Hey there! Which version of Excel is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, note the use of `MIN()`:

```
=IF(A1=1,1,IF(AND(A1>1,A1<=10),2,IF(AND(A1>10,A1<=50),MIN(5,A1*0.25),IF(A1>=51,MIN(25,0.1*A1)))))
```

where `A1` is the value of the population.

Answer (score 0):

I have clarified the parameters by changing the layout of your formula to:

```
=IF(G4=1,1,
    IF(AND(G4>1,G4<=10),2,
       IF(AND(OR(G4>10,G4<=50),(0.25*G4),
                 AND(G4>50,(0.1*G4),G4>25,25)
             ),IF(G4>5,5)
         )
      )
   )
```

Several things become clear:

- The final `IF()` has a true value, but no false value.
- The final `AND()` checks 4 values, two conditional and two numeric.
- The previous `AND()` checks 3 values, an `OR()`, a numeric and an `AND()`.

I'm not sure how you were trying to formulate your conditions, but there are clearly some `IF()` clauses missing.

Note that your `AND()` clauses are unnecessary, since one of the conditions is implicit in each case, so I would propose:

```
=IF(G4<=1,G4=1,
    IF(G4<=10,2,
       IF(G4<=50,
            IF(G4>20,5,0.25*G4),
            IF(G4>250,25,0.1*G4)
         )
      )
   )
```

I have added allowing for a sample size of zero if `G4` is zero or negative. I have compared population size limits to save calculating the sample size twice (which is also avoided in Bruce Wayne's use of `MIN()`).